# Determining optimal Write Batch Size in Azure Data Factory's copy task

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I was looking into optimizing some of the pipelines that we have got and as a part of it, also looked at the Write batch Size option of copy tasks. I understand how it basically works and its importance. Quoting MSDN:

> Copy Activity inserts data in a series of batches. You can set the
>   number of rows in a batch by using the writeBatchSize property. If
>   your data has small rows, you can set the writeBatchSize property with
>   a higher value to benefit from lower batch overhead and higher
>   throughput. If the row size of your data is large, be careful when you
>   increase writeBatchSize. A high value might lead to a copy failure
>   caused by overloading the database.

But what is the correct way to determining the perfect metric. I have prepared an excel sheet with the table names, their size (in MB) and count of records in it. What should be my next steps, considering I don't have time to go into extensive hit and trial? Any pointers would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

If it matters, I am on P4 Azure SQL DB and pulling data from Oracle ERP tables.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance Have you check this doc?